# Is there any way to create and deploy Rinkeby test faucet from scratch?

Tags: testing, ethereum, smartcontracts

I am trying to see if there is any way to create a smart contract and deploy a Rinkeby test faucet from scratch. I could not find any tutorial talking about this! Does anyone have an idea of the technology behind creating such a faucet, for example, https://rinkebyfaucet.com/ or https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby ? How do these companies develop their Rinkeby fauces, and do they pay actual money when they send us 0.1 ETH?

Comment: I really doubt the actual money part but i am looking for the same thing but couldn't find anything. I mean i was looking for some thing that can help me build a custom faucet so i can test my app but no luck so far